# SignalR connection timeouts if browser tab is inactive

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr

If I keep browser tab active (open it at least once per 5-6 mins) my WebSocket connection keeps alive through ping requests (see attached screenshot). But if I abandon the tab for 10 minutes or so, /ping requests stop happening and WebSocket connection terminates.
Any explanation for this and how can it be bypassed to keep connection alive while device is awake?

PS: I suspect that our recent migration to Azure Web services could be related. Or some browser policies could change. Having SignalR implemented for a few years we now experience such issues for the first time.

[image]

Comment: You have code like this that reensures reconnect on close?https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/d78a1c22f8242734ad2745f94887ce6bdfdce5de/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/signalR.eventAggregator.js#L159

Comment: I too an seeing this issue on an application that has been working correctly for a while. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I think it may be connected to the throttling that is introduced in Chrome 88. https://blog.chromium.org/2020/11/tab-throttling-and-more-performance.html . Are you seeing the issue in all browsers?

Comment: I've filed an issue on Github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4536#issue-822830561

Answer (score 4):

We were able to mitigate the issue by increasing disconnect timeout to 90s and setting keep alive property to 10s on the server (ASP.NET app).

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

But I'm still waiting for an official response on Github.

Comment: We faced the same issue, thank you for providing this workaround until an upstream fix is available (either in SignalR or Chromium)!

Answer (score 2):

It could be a tab freezing feature on the browser.

I have copied this directly from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0#:%7E:text=Automatically%20reconnect%20The%20JavaScript%20client%20for%20SignalR%20can,on%20HubConnectionBuilder.%20It%20won%27t%20automatically%20reconnect%20by%20default.)

> Some browsers have a tab freezing or sleeping
> feature to reduce computer resource usage for inactive tabs. This can
> cause SignalR connections to close and may result in an unwanted user
> experience. Browsers use heuristics to figure out if a tab should be
> put to sleep, such as:
>
> - Playing audio
> - Holding a web lock
> - Holding an IndexedDB lock
> - Being connected to a USB device
> - Capturing video or audio
> - Being mirrored
> - Capturing a window or display
>
> **Note:** These heuristics may change over time or differ between browsers.
> Check your support matrix and figure out what method works best for
> your scenarios.
>
> To avoid putting an app to sleep, the app should trigger one of the
> heuristics that the browser uses.
>
> The following code example shows how to use a Web Lock to keep a tab
> awake and avoid an unexpected connection closure.
>
> JavaScript
>
> ```
> Copy
> var lockResolver;
> if (navigator && navigator.locks && navigator.locks.request) {
>     const promise = new Promise((res) => {
>         lockResolver = res;
>     });
>
>     navigator.locks.request('unique_lock_name', { mode: "shared" }, () => {
>         return promise;
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> For the preceding code example:
>
> Web Locks are experimental. The conditional check confirms that the
> browser supports Web Locks. The promise resolver (lockResolver) is
> stored so that the lock can be released when it's acceptable for the
> tab to sleep. When closing the connection, the lock is released by
> calling lockResolver(). When the lock is released, the tab is allowed
> to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben Cameron already stated, I also thinkt it may be connected to the throttling mechanism.
See StackOverflow post regarding this issue (contains solution idea):
[SignalR and/or timer issues since Chrome 88](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496547/signalr-and-or-timer-issues-since-chrome-88)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has fixed already.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31079

**Solution is just to update your signalr npm package to the latest version.**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr

Since Chrome 88, intensive throttling happens to timers in the following conditions.(https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/)

- The page has been hidden for more than 5 minutes.
- The chain count is 5 or greater.
- The page has been silent for at least 30 seconds.
- WebRTC is not in use.

Above timer throttling causes signalr connection broken.