# SignalR and/or timer issues since Chrome 88

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timer, signalr

We have an ASP.Net WebForms application that uses SignalR (v2.4.1) to do some bi-directional communications between server and client. It's worked fine for years: connections are stable, hundreds of users use it, etc.

However, we've started to get sporadic reports of connection problems from across our client base, all reporting the same thing: if the browser (Chrome) session goes idle for more than 5 minutes, the connection drops in the background. All timers in the page stop being run regularly, which (amongst other things) stops "keepalives" stop being sent, and eventually the connection fails with the client-side error:

```
The client has been inactive since <date> and it has exceeded the inactivity timeout of 50000 ms. Stopping the connection.
```

Standard procedure after this would be to automatically restart the connection, but this doesn't do anything. If/when the user reactivates the page (e.g. by switching to the tab), everything starts to spring back into life, albeit with a closed SignalR connection.

After much investigation, it seems that we're being impacted by [this change](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/) introduced in Chrome v88, where timers (`setTimeout`s) are severely restricted if

- The page has been hidden for more than 5 minutes
- The timer has been "chained" 5 or more times - I'm assuming this is similar to recursion, where the timer calls itself.
- Page has been "silent" for 30 seconds

The 5 minutes/30 seconds condition fits with the reports we're getting. However, we're running pretty basic Javascript on our page: there are only two uses of `setTimeout` in our own code, neither of which could ever "chain" (recurse) onto themselves. We also cannot replicate the issue: it's happened to us in testing, but we can't *make* it happen reliably. Disabling this feature via `chrome://flags/#intensive-wake-up-throttling` seems to mitigate the issue - but of course, we can't make this a requirement to use our site.

The only other Javascript running on the site is `jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js`, and from the SignalR source, there are lots of `setTimeout`s in there. Could SignalR be impacted by this change in Chrome; perhaps when it tries to silently reconnect after a temporary network issue or some other unpredictable event?

If not, is there any way, in any browser or IDE, to track which timers have been launched (and, more importantly, "chained"), so we can see what could be triggering this restriction?

Comment: I cannot recreate in my usage either but the link/doc does state that - "Intensive throttling happens to timers that are scheduled when none of the minimal throttling or throttling conditions apply, and all of the following conditions are true." So, if you have nothing chained then it should not be forcing the intensive throttling because not all conditions are true. Maybe reach out to the author as he suggests - https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/

Comment: This answer can be useful to temporary mitigate the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585979/2551398

Comment: Same issues was reported in our application, maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587277/chrome-timers-throttling-and-microsoft-signalr-issue/67598257#67598257) could help to get more info about problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We're as well facing issues with our signalR (WebSockets as transport). We're not able to reproduce it in our lab. The HAR files of our customer and extended logging provided us only the information that the client "consuming only after following interesting groups" is not sending pings within the default 30 seconds needed to keep the connection. Therefore the server closes the connection. We added logs in the signalR client library and only saw the ping timer not being hit on time. No error, no nothing. (Client is JavaScript and the issue occurred on customer site in chrome 87 (throttling was implemented there already for half of the chrome users - https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#87))

And the world is slowly getting aware of "an issue": https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4536

Our quick help for our customers will be to create an ET with a manual broadcast ping-pong mechanism from the server site and each client will have to answer. Avoiding being dependent on the JavaScript ping in the signalR library until a "better" solution or fix is provided.

Comment: After two days of testing on customer site the issue seems to be resolved with our solution of an additional heartbeat mechanism.

We've implemented a BackgroundService and injected our signalR hub, where we call "await hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("Heartbeat", stoppingToken);" insde the ExecuteAsync method - Ref for backgroundServices: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1

On the frontend we simply implemented the method and response with connection.invoke("AckHeartbeat") going to an enmpty method in the server hub for the keepalive.

Comment: How do you fire the `AckHeartbeat` code on the front end? I'm presuming you sent that periodically to effectively keep SignalR alive, but if you do that with a `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, how do you avoid that being caught up in Chrome's timer throttling?

Comment: The server sends the heartbeat over the Hub every 20s. The client receives the heartbeat from the server as message which instantly triggers a client site method to return a message to the server with connection.invoke("Ackheartbeat"). 
This makes the server site to be responsible for the interval and the client simply reacts to the event it receives periodically. Since the interval logic is on server site, the throttling of chrome does not take effect.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, javascript library that does the ping can be modified, to slightly change the way that it uses the timers. One of the conditions for intensive throttling is that the `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` chain count is 5+. This can be avoided for recurring calls, by using a web worker. The main thread can post a dummy message to the web worker, which does nothing other than posting a dummy message back to the main thread. The subsequent `setTimeout()` call can be made on the message event from the web worker.

i.e.,

1. main_thread_ping_function :- doPing() -> post_CallMeBack_ToWebWorker()
2. web_worker :- onmessage -> post_CallingYouBack_ToMainThread()
3. main_thread :- web_worker.onmessage -> setTimeout(main_thread_ping_function, timeoutValue)

Since the `setTimeout()` is called on a message from web worker, rather than from the `setTimout()` execution flow, the chain length remains one, and thus no intensive throttling would be done by chrome 88+.

Note that, chained `setTimeout()` calls in a web worker are not throttled by chrome at the moment, and thus defining the timer functionality inside a web worker, and acting on the messages(to perform ping) from web worker, too solves the problem. However, if chrome developers decide to throttle the timers in web workers too, in the future, it gets broken again.

A utility(similar to java scheduled executor) which allows scheduling of callbacks using web workers, to avoid throttling, by context switching:

```js
class NonThrottledScheduledExecutor {


  constructor(callbackFn, initialDelay, delay) {
    this.running = false;
    this.callback = callbackFn;
    this.initialDelay = initialDelay;
    this.delay = delay;
  };

  start() {
    if (this.running) {
      return;
    }
    this.running = true;
    // Code in worker.
    let workerFunction = "onmessage = function(e) { postMessage('fireTimer'); }";
    this.worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerFunction], {
      type: 'text/javascript'
    })));
    // On a message from worker, schedule the next round.
    this.worker.onmessage = (e) => setTimeout(this.fireTimerNow.bind(this), this.delay);
    // Start the first round.
    setTimeout(this.fireTimerNow.bind(this), this.initialDelay);

  };

  fireTimerNow() {
    if (this.running) {
      this.callback();
      // dummy message to be posted to web worker.
      this.worker.postMessage('callBackNow');
    }
  };

  stop() {
    if (this.running) {
      this.running = false;
      this.worker.terminate();
      this.worker = undefined;
    }
  };

};
```

```html
<button onclick="startExecutor()">Start Executor</button>
<button onclick="stopExecutor()">Stop Executor</button>
<div id="op"></div>
<script>
  var executor;
  
  function startExecutor() {
    if (typeof(executor) == 'undefined') {
      // Schedules execution of 'doThis' function every 2seconds, after an intial delay of 1 sec
      executor = new NonThrottledScheduledExecutor(doThis, 1000, 2000);
      executor.start();
      console.log("Started scheduled executor");
    }
  }

  function stopExecutor() {
    if (typeof(executor) != 'undefined') {
      executor.stop();
      executor = undefined;
      document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = "Executor stopped at " + l;
    }
  }

  var l = 0;

  function doThis() {
    l = l + 1;
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = "Executor running... I will run even when the my window is hidden.. counter: " + l;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft have released SignalR 2.4.2, which should address the issue natively and avoid the need for any manual workarounds.

Nuget package available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/2.4.2), and the list of fixed issues is [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20sort%3Aupdated-desc%20is%3Aclosed%20milestone%3A2.4.2%20)

Answer (score 1):

I know that it does not solve the problem altogether with chrome, however, the new edge that uses chromium engine has added a few new settings to govern the timeouts (since it was affected too by the change). There is a new whitelisting option that gives at least the power to the users to decide which pages are excluded from this behavior. I honestly do believe that these setting will be added by google sooner or later. Until then we recommend our customers to switch to edge if they are affected.

You can find it in settings\system:
[image: screenshot]