# Chrome DevTools Network tool for websockets internals

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, signalr

Stuck at problem - @microsoft/signalr send ping messages (not a internal websockets ping frames), but sometimes it stop sending that messages. Chrome dev tools indicates, that client wont send ping message to server, then server closes connection with `code: 1000; wasClean: true` parameters on `CloseEvent`

Websocket.send method has `void` return type, that, i guess, "fire-and-forget" behaviour.

Question is:
Does chrome dev tools show any message, that client trying to send, and observes `Websocket` class instances OR dev tools uses internal classes or low-level interfaces (e.g. opened socket)? For example, if network connection has problems at message sending time (for example, connection on proxy was lost for 2-3 seconds), does DevTool shows that lost message or not?

Does network problems affect internal message queue?

Can i access to internal queue to determine, that queued message was sent to network/network interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was answered in [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496547/signalr-and-or-timer-issues-since-chrome-88/66559799#66559799)