# Chrome timers throttling and @microsoft/signalr issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, web-applications, settimeout

Accordingly blogpost from Jake Archibald, from [Chrome 88 implements 3 stages of throttling](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/)

Accordingly throttling implementation from [Chrome 57](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs)

> There are a number of automatic exemptions from this throttling:
>
> > Applications playing audio are considered foreground and aren’t throttled.

> > **Applications with real-time connections (WebSockets and WebRTC), to avoid closing these connections by timeout. The run-timers-once-a-second rule is still applied in these cases.**

Second cite imeratively says, that once application has Websocket connection, application exempt from throttling.

The fact is, we use @microsoft/signalr library as top-level api for websocket connections, and this library uses internal ping (not a ping opcodes) messages, wrapped with setTimeout. After 5 minutes of background work, that timer throtlled and stops sending ping messages, thats leads to  close event and websocket connection being closed.

I'm asking for more detailed explanation:

Does Chorome 88 enbles throttling for applications, that have real-time connections?

Does timers will be throttled regardless websocket connection appeareance and only websocket instances exempt from throttling?

Answer (score 0):

accordingly [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496547/signalr-and-or-timer-issues-since-chrome-88/66559799#66559799) same issues reported.

Quick explanation is:
As Jake wrote in blogpost about heavy throttling

> the browser will check timers in this group **once per minute**. Similar to before, this means timers will batch together in these minute-by-minute checks.

That is! After 5 minutes tab spent in background, signalr ping algorithm will be throttled to 1 minute, BUT default values for `keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds` = 15sec and `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` = 30sec, thats twice smaller than heavy throttling timer delaying time and for server side it is count as ping failure that is predicate for [lifetime methods invocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#transportdisconnect) and stopping the connection, but first, server side trying to stop connection with disconnect handshake, and physically client is still connected, the result is - `CloseEvent with code 1000 and wasClean = true`. This behaviour wount produce any errors.

**Front-end clients must update version of @microsoft/signalr to >= 5.0.6 to solve this problem. [Changes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/41caa92bd80008786d27fe782dc8d560ac8d01c6)**